# Kubernetes Service not able to get External IP

Tags: kubernetes

The service is external-ip is  and is unable to bind with a external port. I have run the command to try to find the port.

> minikube service mongodb-express-service

There is no error shown on the terminal. But the browser says that it is unable to connect to that url.

**Enviroment**

- Minikube
- Oracle Virtual Box
- Ubuntu 20.04

**mongo-express.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-express
          image: mongo-express
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: username
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: password
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-config-map
                  key: database_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb-express-service
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30001
```

**Update**
**Kubectl get service output**

```
NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes                ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          14d
mongodb-express-service   LoadBalancer   10.106.190.5     <pending>     8081:30001/TCP   2d3h
mongodb-service           ClusterIP      10.110.241.194   <none>        27017/TCP        3d23h
```

**Kubectl get pod output**

```
mongo-express-85bdd6688f-mhv2x        1/1     Running   2          2d3h
mongodb-deployment-7f79c5f88f-h9dvf   1/1     Running   2          2d3h
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting this answer to give more reference on 2 topics:

- Kubernetes Service not able to get External IP
- Issue that was present in this question

---

#### Kubernetes Service not able to get External IP

`Service` of type `LoadBalancer`:

> Exposes the Service externally **using a cloud provider's load balancer**. `NodePort` and `ClusterIP` Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

In a Kubernetes solution like `minikube` you won't get out of the box `External IP` that is associated with `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`. You don't need the `External IP` to connect to your `Services`. You can connect to your `Services` by **either**:

- Using a `NodePort` (`$ minikube service xyz` is using it)
- Using a `$ minikube tunnel` (this would "assign" `External IP`'s)
- `Virtualbox` specific:

  - Use `metallb` ([load-balancer implementation for bare metal Kubernetes clusters](https://metallb.universe.tf/)) to allocate the range for your `LoadBalancers` from a subnet that Host-only networking adapter uses with `minikube`.

---

#### Issue that was present in this question

The issue that was present in the question was connected with the mismatch between the `Service` `.spec.selector` and `Deployment` `.spec.selector.matchLabels`.

The easiest way to check if your `selector` is configured correctly (apart from looking at the `YAML` manifest), is by:

- `$ kubectl get endpoints`

```sh
NAME         ENDPOINTS                AGE
kubernetes   A.B.C.D:443              28m
nginx    --> 10.32.0.13:80 <--        5s
```

> Disclaimer!
>
> The `endpoint` will be present when `Pod` is in `Running` state and `Ready`.

If the `nginx` (`Service` name) `endpoints` was empty it could mean a mismatched selector or issue with the `Pod` (`CrashLoopBackOff`, `Pending`, etc.).

You can also check this by:

- `$ kubectl describe svc SERVICE_NAME` <-- `Endpoints` field
- `$ kubectl describe endpoints SERVICE_NAME` <-- `Subsets.addresses` field

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*
- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Handbook: Accessing](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/)*

Answer (score 1):

You didn't connect your LoadBalancer to your mongo-express deployment. Change selector -> app to mongo-express

```yaml
###... previous config here
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30001
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of resource missing in your application. If you have created it already then please verify with mine. else create it.

> 1: create Configmap resource

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-config-map
data:
  database_url: mongodb-service
```

> 2: create Secret resource

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: dXNlcm5hbWU=
  password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

> 3: On a terminal

```
minikube service mongodb-express-service
```

Below is the output of my terminal you may vary.

```
|-----------|-------------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |          NAME           | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|-------------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | mongodb-express-service |        8081 | http://192.168.49.2:30001 |
|-----------|-------------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service mongodb-express-service.
|-----------|-------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |          NAME           | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|-------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | mongodb-express-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:53898 |
|-----------|-------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service default/mongodb-express-service in default browser...
```

*Edit Updated:*

> I've verify your manifests and noticed that the `Service selector` doesn't match the `Deployment selector`. Change the `Service: spec.selector` to `app: mongo-express` instead of: `app: mongodb-express-service`.